# Parameter required for django view with json decorator - how?

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, jqplot

I have a django page (*search_form.html*) with a form text field/button that triggers an action that goes and searches a database with the value entered. The results are displayed on another django page (*search_results.html*). The form snippet from the **search_form.html** looks like this:

```
    <form action="/datest/partner_search/" method="get">
        <label class="control-label">Partner ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="partnerQ">
        <input type="submit" value="Partner Search">
    </form>
```

I have the following in my app **urls.py**

```
url(r'^search_form/$', views.search_form, name='search_form'),
url(r'^search_results/$', views.search_results, name='search_results'),
```

And I have the following in **views.py**

```
def partner_search(request):
    error = False
    if 'partnerQ' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET['partnerQ']
        if not q:
            error = True
        else:
            my_data = MyTable.objects.filter(dbField__icontains=q)
            return render(request, 'myapp/search_results.html', {'mydata': my_data, 'query': q})
    return render(request, 'myapp/search_form.html', {'error': error})
```

This works ok, but my problem comes when I want to include a jqplot graph in the results page, but the data to be plotted on the graph needs a DB Query based on the partnerQ string passed to the above views.py method. So I have a separate method that is meant to create the JSON data for jqplot in my views.py. So the additional entry in **urls.py** looks like:

```
url(r'^my_plot_json/$', views.my_plot_json, name='my_plot_json'),
```

The **views.py** method (which still needs to string from the search field - don't know how to capture this) looks like the following. Note - I know this won't work as I haven't passed q

```
@render_to_json()
def my_plot_json(request):
    mydata = MyTable.objects.values("iDate").filter(dbField__icontains=q).annotate(Count("id"))
    jsondataset = [[str(z['iDate']), z['id__count']] for z in mydata]
    return [jsondataset]
```

The corresponding javascript snippet looks like this:

```
function populateGraph() {
    $.get('/myapp/my_plot_json', function(data) { drawTwelveMonthPlot(data); });
}
```

So my problem in summary is this _ I need to perform a separate DB query to generate the JSON data for my jqPlot graph but I can't figure out how to capture the search string that's entered in the form field for the my_plot_json method. Options as I see it could be:

1. Pass the string in a call to **my_plot_json** from within the **partner_search** method?
2. Have two actions attributed to my form field so both routines are triggered?

I don't know if either of those are possible and admittedly, I'm a bit of a python/django newbie so would appreciate code-snippet style solutions if possible. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Various solutions spring to mind, but surely the easiest is just to generate the json in the partner_search method itself, and pass it to the template along with the other parameters. Then you can call `drawTwelveMonthPlot` directly with that data, rather than making a separate Ajax request for it.

**Edit**

I don't really see what you don't understand. You have a function, `populateGraph`, which simply contains an Ajax call, and the result of that Ajax call is passed to `drawTwelveMonthPlot`. So you can simply take the invocation of `drawTwelveMonthPlot` out of that Ajax call and invoke it directly, passing it the JSON from the template.

```
function populateGraph() {
    var data = '{{ json_data_from_view|safe }}'
    drawTwelveMonthPlot(data);
}
```

That assumes that the JS is in your Django template; if it isn't, you can just put the `var data...` line in a `<script>` element in your template, and the rest will still work.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but I'm not at all sure how I call the Javascript directly. As things stands, the HTML simply has a div ID that's used in drawTwelveMonthPlot. If the JSON data I need isn't in at the URL above (/myapp/my_plot_json) then I"m not sure how else I can pass the data to it for plotting. Sorry to be a pain - newbie alert.